# Invalid Characters in Path while Compression in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am having a problem where I am trying to ZIP up a file using the below code :-

```
        Process msinfo = new Process();
        msinfo.StartInfo.FileName = "msinfo32.exe";
        string path = "\"" + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + @"\test.nfo" + "\"";
        string zippath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + @"\test.nfo";
        MessageBox.Show(path);
        msinfo.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/nfo "+path;
        //msinfo.Start();
        //msinfo.WaitForExit();
        //MessageBox.Show("The File Has Been Saved!");
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(zippath, @"C:\Test.zip");
        MessageBox.Show("Everything Is Done!");
```

The error that is coming is that the Folder path is not valid. I also tried by including quotation marks in the Zippath variable but it did not work.

PS - My machine name has 3 words so it has got spaces as well. Help is appreciated ^_^

Comment: There is no way something like "\C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop" (notice initial slash) is valid path. Make sure to post value you see in you message box (or better yet use hardcoded values in sample code to avoid any guesses what went wrong).

Comment: That isn't an initial slash. It's an escaped `"`. The path translates to: `"\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\test.nfo"`.

Comment: CreateFromDirectory() requires the first argument to be a directory.  It isn't, it is a file.  Just like the error message says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` should be a path of a directory, not a file (test.nfo in this case).
If you want compress the whole directory (e.g. the Desktop dir) then omit the "test.nfo" from the path, like this:

```
string zippath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
```

If you want to create a zip archive from only one file then use the [ZipFileExtensions.CreateEntryFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485724(v=vs.110).aspx).

One more thing: when you want to build a path from two or more components use the [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of simple string concatenation. It can spare you from a lot of pain (like adding path separator characters).

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the solution. Much Appreciated ^_^